# Angularjs datepicker max bug?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, max

When I set the input type to date and set a max validation, the maximum date could be selected to the max date. It is OK. But when I choose the max date as input, it always shows invalid. It is no problem to pick other days except the max date. It supposes to limit to the date one day before the max date? But why it still can be picked?

Comment: What do you mean by 'It's alwas shown as invalid'? It's occured during the form validation ? Could you show us some code with us ?

Comment: Thanks for your replying. I finally figured it out: I used new Date() to set initial date to current date. Every time a new date is picked up, My model only changed the date but keep the time.  However, when I set the max it actually set to time to 00:00:00 (I believe so, because max only need date). So when they are compared, the whole datetime is compared and of course the pickup time will always be larger than the max datetime! I am not sure if my understanding is right or not. But anyway, I built a new initial date using new Date()'s year, month, date, then there is no problem any more.